# Is $\mathcal{B}^{\mathbb{Z}}(l^\infty(\mathbb{Z}))$ a commutative algebra?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, banach-algebras

Consider $l^\infty(\mathbb{Z})$ the Banach space of bounded complex valued functions on the abelian group $\mathbb{Z}$ with the supremum norm. It has a natural action by $\mathbb{Z}$ given by $(zf)(g):=f(z^{-1}g)$. Then let $\mathcal{B}^{\mathbb{Z}}(l^\infty(\mathbb{Z}))$ be the algebra (multiplication by composition) consisting of all bounded $\mathbb{Z}$-equivariant operators $l^\infty(\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow l^\infty(\mathbb{Z})$.

Question: Is this a commutative algebra?

If $l^\infty$ is replaced by $l^2$ the algebra is the von Neumann algebra $L(\mathbb{Z})$ and in this cases $\mathbb{C}(\mathbb{Z})$ lies densely (wrt WOT or SOT) in $L(\mathbb{Z})$ as a subalgebra and therefore $L(\mathbb{Z})$ is commutative. But I think $\mathbb{C}(\mathbb{Z})$ does not lie densely in $\mathcal{B}^{\mathbb{Z}}(l^\infty(\mathbb{Z}))$, so the situation is a bit different.

Question: What happens if $\mathbb{Z}$ is replaced by an arbitrary abelian group?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following is an abstract (Banach) algebraic take on Werner's construction.  Let $A=\ell^1(\mathbb Z)$ with convolution (but in general $A$ is any Banach algebra).  We turn the dual space $A^*$ into an $A$-bimodule (though in our example, $A$ is commutative) by dualising the actions:
$$ (a\cdot f)(b) = f(ba), \quad (f\cdot a)(b) = f(ab) \qquad
(f\in A^*, a,b\in A). $$
Then you can check that $T:A^*\rightarrow A^*$ is $\mathbb Z$-equivariant if and only if $T$ is a module homomorphism: I'll write $T\in\hom_A(A^*)$ to mean $T(f\cdot a) = T(f)\cdot a$ (the right action is more appropriate in the non-commutative group setting).  If $e\in A$ is the unit then
$$ T(f)(a) = T(f)(ae) = (T(f)\cdot a)(e) = T(f\cdot a)(e)
\qquad (T\in \hom_A(A^*), f\in A^*, a\in A). $$
So again $T$ is determined uniquely by $m\in A^{**}, m(f) = T(f)(e)$.  Conversely, given $m\in A^{**}$ we can define $T\in\hom_A(A^*)$ by this relation.  So $\hom_A(A^*)\cong A^{**}$.  A similar result holds if $A$ only has a bounded approximate identity.

So $A^{**}$ becomes an algebra for the product induced from $\hom_A(A^*)$.  Define $$ (m\cdot f)(a) = m(f\cdot a) \qquad (m\in A^{**}, f\in A^*,a\in A).$$
Then if $m_i$ is associated to $T_i$ for $i=1,2$,
$$ (m_1m_2)(f) = (T_1\circ T_2)(f)(e) = T_1(T_2(f))(e)
= m_1(T_2(f)). $$
However, for $a\in A$,
$$ T_2(f)(a) = m_2(f\cdot a) = (m_2\cdot f)(a) $$
and so
$$ (m_1m_2)(f) = m_1(m_2\cdot f) $$
This is precisely the "1st Arens product", say $\Box$, as studied in Banach algebra theory.  By making the symmetric choices we get the "2nd Arens product", say $\diamond$, which might differ.  If $A$ is commutative then $m_1\Box m_2 = m_2\diamond m_1$ and so $\hom_A(A^*)$ is commutative precisely when the Arens products agree.

However, Young showed in "The irregularity of multiplication in group algebras"
Quart J. Math. Oxford Ser. (2) 24 (1973), 59–62, [MathSciNet](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=320756) that for any locally compact group $G$, we have that $L^1(G)$ is not Arens regular.  So Werner's question has a negative answer for all Abelian groups (with the axiom of choice!)

Comment: Delurking to say: very nice!

Comment: Minor nitpick: your last paragraph is missing the word "infinite" in both sentences. (Please don't thump me for pedantry!) Also, just to make explicit something which I think is tacit in your final sentence: without choice, we could have $hom_A(A^*)=A$ for $A=\ell^1(G)$ for every $G$, in which case Werner's question has a *positive* answer for all Abelian groups.

Answer (score 2):

I might have an answer to the problem which depends on the set theoretic axioms used. I would be glad if someone could double check this.

Let $G=\mathbb{Z}$. First observe the following: Let $\chi$ be a functional in the dual space $l^\infty(G)'$. A $G$-equivariant linear bounded operator $A:l^\infty(G)\rightarrow l^\infty(G)$ is uniquely determined by the value $A(f)(1)$ for each $f\in l^\infty(G)$. So define $\varphi(\chi)$ to be the operator $A$ with $A(f)(1)=\chi(f)$. One has to check that this gives a bounded operator wrt to the sup-norm, but that is easy. We have defined a map $\varphi:\mathcal{B}^G(l^\infty(G))\rightarrow l^\infty(G)'$. One can easily find an inverse to this map, so it is bijective.
Now one can calculate a formula for the product on $l^\infty(G)'$ which respects $\varphi$. It can be written as
$$(\chi*\tilde{\chi})(f)=\chi\big(g\mapsto\tilde{\chi}(f(g\_))\big)$$
We will give two elements in $l^\infty(G)'$ which do not commute wrt to this product. This will crucially use the axiom of choice (see also below). Denote by $c$ the Banach space of functions on $G$ such that the limit for $x\rightarrow -\infty$ and also the limit for $x\rightarrow\infty$ exists and take the sup-norm as norm. Define two elements $\chi$ and $\tilde{\chi}$ in $c'$ as follows:
$$\chi(f)=\lim_+f+\lim_-f$$
$$\tilde{\chi}(f)=\lim_+f-\lim_-f$$
where $\lim_-$ means the limit for $x\rightarrow -\infty$ and $\lim_+$ means the limit for $x\rightarrow\infty$. Using Hahn-Banach extend these functionals to $l^\infty(G)$ (axiom of choice!). Now choose any bounded function $F:G\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ which converges to $0$ in the negative and to $1$ in the positive. It is now easy to see that
$$(\chi*\tilde{\chi})(F)=2$$
but
$$(\tilde{\chi}*\chi)(F)=0$$

Weakening the axiom of choice AC to dependent choice DC and adding another axiom yields that $l^\infty(G)'=l^1(G)$, see: Martin Väth, [The dual space of L∞ is L1](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019357798800396), Indag. Mathem., N.S., 9 (4), 1998, 619–625. That is, every functional on $l^\infty(G)$ is given by pointwise multiplication with a function in $l^1(G)$. It is easy to see that the product above is commutative in this case.