# Representations of the algebra of shift-invariant operators on $\ell^\infty({\mathbb Z})$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-algebras

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb Z}$
By an operator on $\ell^\infty(\Z)$, I mean a bounded linear map $\ell^\infty(\Z)\to\ell^\infty(\Z)$. (Note that I am not assuming weak-star continuity.) By shift-invariance, I mean that such a map $T$ should commute with the shift operator $S:\ell^\infty(\Z)\to\ell^\infty(\Z)$ that is defined by $(S\xi)(n) = \xi(n-1)$.

Let $B$ denote the algebra of all shift-invariant operators on $\ell^\infty(\Z)$. It is known, as a special case of general Banach-algebraic results, that $B$ may be identified with $\ell^1(\Z)^{**}$ equipped with the first Arens product; in particular, $B$ is highly non-commutative, since it contains a copy of the semigroup $\beta\Z$. (See [this question and its answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/145849/is-mathcalb-mathbbzl-infty-mathbbz-a-commutative-algebra) for some related background.)

**Question 1.** Does there exist an infinite-dimensional Banach space $X$ and a continuous representation $\pi: B \to {\cal B}(X)$ which is irreducible, in the strict algebraic sense (i.e. the only non-zero $\pi(B)$-invariant linear subspace of $X$ is $X$ itself)?

**Question 2.** As in Question 1, but with "irreducible" weakened to "topologically irreducible".